# Adding text in front of separate numbers in list

Tags: python, list, random, text

Im new to python and hit a wall with my last print in my program
I got a list of numbers created with math int(numbers that when printed looks like this
**[0, 0, 0, 0]** #just with random numbers from 1 - 1000

I want to add text in front of every random number in list and print it out like this
**[Paul 0 Frederick 0 Ape 0 Ida 0]**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? What have you researched? Edit your question to illustrate your attempt at meeting this requirement as described before posting here, in accordance with [ask].

Comment: Where does the text come from? Any answers we come up with where we just guess are unlikely to be useful to you, so show us what you've tried and maybe we can help fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to make a dictionary. You could type:

```
d = dict()
d["Paul"] = random.randint(1,100)
....
print(d)


#output: {"Paul":1, "Fredrick":50, "Ape":25, "Ida":32}
```

Alternatively there is nothing stopping you from using strings and integers in the same list! Python is not <s>strongly</s> statically typed.

If you have a list of numbers [45,5,59,253] and you want to add names to them you probably need a loop.

```
nums = [45,5,59,253]
names = ["Paul", "Frederick", "Ape", "Ida"]
d = dict()

i = 0
for n in nums:
    d[names[i]] = n
    i+=1
```

or if you wanted a list

```
nums = [45,5,59,253]
names = ["Paul", "Frederick", "Ape", "Ida"]

list = [x for y in zip(names, nums) for x in y]
```

Comment: Just to be a pedant, python _is_ strongly typed, but it is not _statically_ typed.

Comment: It all depends on what format he wants the output though. Dictionnary is great and easy to create and use, list with mixed types is pretty good, and if he wants the exact output from his question then its simple to make but not practical later.

Comment: My description wasn't as clear as I wanted it to be. The list of numbers is actually a list created by math. So the numbers aren't random just not always the same based of the user input

Comment: excatly what I was looking for. Thanks !                                                                      
nums = [45,5,59,253]
names = ["Paul", "Frederick", "Ape", "Ida"]

list = [x for y in zip(names, nums) for x in y]

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to turn your random integers into strings and add them to the text (string) you want.
Example:

```
lst=[]
x = str(randint(0,1000))
text = 'Alex'
final_text = text+' '+x
lst.append(final_text)
```

Just added the space like in your example. It'll just be a little more complex to access the numbers if you do it this way.